# Usage of word "friends"

Tags: american-english, british-english, subcontinental-english

This is from a news article:

*"Mr. Trump’s desire to be friends with the “short and fat” ruler of North Korea"*

My doubt is that, can we use friends here because friend seems better here. Other examples to take can be:

I want to be friend with him.
I want to be friends with them

Which is the way to use "friend" with a "s"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plural is used here because it refers to Kim and Trump becoming friends. You could rephrase it to make the grammar used more obvious:

"Mr. Trump wants that Kim and he become friends". The desired end state is "Trump and kim *are* friend*s*".

You can also say "Mr. Trump wants to become Kim's friend", but that has a slightly different tone and puts Trump on a lower "level" than Kim. Using the wording with plural "friends" implies some kind of a mutual, equal relationship.

Comment: I was just blown by the explanation . Thank you. That level thing i was un aware of